# Pushing routes in OpenVPN not working on iOS?

Tags: networking, ssh, routing, openvpn

Because of a certain public government firewall with deep packet inspection preventing OpenVPN out of the country, I am trying to run OpenVPN over SSH. I also wanted all traffic to run through OpenVPN, so I added `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp` to my server config. To prevent OpenVPN from killing the SSH connection that it ran through, I also added `push "route [server ip] 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"`.

This works beautifully...at least on Windows. But with OpenVPN Connect in conjunction with an iOS SSH app with port forwarding, OpenVPN kills the SSH connection a few seconds after it connects thru the SSH tunnel.

I've tried adding `route [server ip] 255.255.255.255 net_gateway` to the client .ovpn, but to little avail. Are my configs wrong, or do I really need jailbreak (really a last resort) to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn) states:

> bypass-dhcp -- Add a direct route to the DHCP server (if it is non-local) which bypasses the tunnel (Available on Windows clients, may not be available on non-Windows clients).

so there is no certainty at all this exists on iOS. I do not have an iOS device, please let me know whether you find **any** evidence that this instruction works.

Also, as stated above, this **bypasses the tunnel**, which means your information is sent outside the secure OpenVPN tunnel. Are you sure this is what you are after?

Lastly, OpenVPN does not tear down the ssh connection at all. Since your use case is one about a hostile environment, you should investigate more carefully why this occurs. Logs on both server and client will help you understand whether this occurs because of an end-point configuration problem, in which case you are safe, or otherwise.

In your shoes, I would try testing your openvpn client configuration by setting up an openvpn server on your pc, and trying to connect locally from your iOS device, using exactly the same configuration for the server as the real, remote server. When this works, connecting to the remote should be a cinch.

I found [these instructions](https://redfern.me/tunneling-openvpn-through-ssh/) delightfully easy to follow.

Comment: Investigating further into the logs, the handshake succeeds, but the ssh connection breaks once OpenVPN is done configuring. This does not happen anywhere else...